# Find the mean and standard deviation for A, for B and for total daily sales (sales of A and B together).

Tags: standard-deviation, variance

A company has $2$ salespeople, $A$ and $B$.

Salesperson $A$ calls $8$ people each day. For each person he contacts he has a $70\%$ chance of making a sale.

Salesperson $B$, who operates **independently** of $A$, contacts $12$ people daily. For each person she contacts, she has a $60\%$ chance of making a sale.

> Find the mean and standard deviation for $A$, for $B$ and for total daily sales $A+B$.

My thought was to use the formula mean $=$ number of trials $*$ probability of success so:

$$ mu(A) = 8 * 0.7 = 5.6$$ and :$$ mu(B) = 12 * 0.6 = 7.2$$ then finally :$$ mu(A+B) = mu(A) + mu(B)$$

Then, standard deviation $std = \sqrt{np(1-p)}$

combined standard deviation using rules for standard deviation and independence is:

$$std (A+B) = \sqrt{var ( A) + var(B)}$$

I know the mean and standard deviations rules will work for the problem, but just unsure if I can apply the mean and standard deviation of the individual calculations as I have outlined above.

Edit: The tags should formally be Rules for Variances and Standard Deviations of Linear Transformation and Rules for Means

Comment: What you're calling mean (with some good intuition) is called the expected value in probability.

Comment: @Furrane would this be the same as the mean required in the question? my concern is calculating the value using the method outlined above i.e. mu(A) = number of trials for A * probability of success of A = 8 * 0.7 = 5.6, would this approach be correct in calculating the mean total daily sales of A?

Comment: Yes I was just pointing out a vocabulary point. The adequate term in probability is expected value but it is the same as the mean.